# information retrieval vs recommendation system

Tags: recommender-system, information-retrieval, ai

Apologizes in advance, if this question is so basic,

**Problem**:

I have read [this](http://sigir.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/p044.pdf) paper and noticed that Information Retrieval can be identified as a field of study whereas Recommender Systems are a technology.

> Information retrieval addresses the information needs of users by
> delivering relevant pieces of information but requires users to convey
> their information needs explicitly. In contrast, recommender systems
> offer personalized suggestions of items automatically. Ultimately,
> both fields help users cope with information overload by providing
> them with relevant items of information.

I have some doubt about the concept and differences between these two. Therefore, I tried to formulate my research question as follows:

Given the information retrieval field as an umbrella term, my goal is to conduct the research on the state-of-the-art recommendation system (technology) which is able to retrieve the best TOP-N (N=5, 10, 20 , ...) search matches, in a dataset,

**Questions**:

1. Is this a legitimate statement in Data Science or AI community?
2. if not, is there a better way to formulate the research question to address recommendation systems?

Comment: Is this for a Master project or similar? If yes this is fine imho (the phrasing could be a bit better but that's ok). What you describe is just the standard search task with a query, afaik recommender systems also include other cases like predicting items that the user likes based on their past behaviour or other users. I would suggest to make the research question more specific wrt to the particular task and/or domain of application, because this is a quite broad topic.